# Spring and eclipseLink refresh?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, eclipselink

So I am doing a Java web project using Spring as ORM and eclipse link.

The problem I am having is that after I insert, delete or update data in my database through my web application, the data is refreshed in the mySQL database, but when I go back to my view page the new data isn't there so I have to restart my whole program for the new data to be displayed.

How can I refresh my web application to display the newly inserted, updated, or deleted data without having to restart my whole program?

Comment: Devil is in the details, which you aren't showing. Are you holding an entity manager long term, configured an application cache or other caches that you aren't updating?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't saying what front end tech you are using. Angular, React, jQuery?

With a library like Angular you just bind an array representing the data to the view. When you update the array the view auto updates.

You would typically update the array on a success response from the server. So, for example, on a 201 (created), in the promise callback (the .then block) you would update the array with the newly added data. Updating the bound array will update the view.

With libraries like jQuery there is no binding to the view. Instead, you would update the array and then update the HTML dynamically via JavaScript. This would typically be done in an AJAX request callback. See the jQuery.ajax method.